# how to screen scrape and put valid href link that will go to that link

Tags: hyperlink, screen-scraping, href

I have scraped a webpage but I want the link to have valid link and will jump to that linkpage when clicked.

ex scraped data: day 1 - Go to my Page - status

I want the Go to my page to jump to whatever link is in its href.

ex. actual html I got

```
<td><a href="javascript:jsFormAuth('summary.php?meetingid=40456&plusday=0');">Go to my Page</a></td>
```

I need it to be like this:

```
<td><a href="http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/summary.php?meetingid=40456&plusday=0');">Go to my Page</a></td>
```

here's my code for scraping:

```
public string ScreenScrape()
        {
            string url = "http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/index.php";
            string strResult = "";

            WebResponse objResponse;
            WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                // Close and clean up the StreamReader
                sr.Close();
            }
            var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            var doc = webGet.Load(url);

            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                att.Value = "http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/"+att.Value;
            }


            return strResult;
        }
```

Here's my attempt to change the link and remove the javascript string but could not figure out how to get to the right index . Also, once I am able to change that, how do I replace each href in the strResult(above) to the new href?

```
    foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
        att.Value = "http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/" + ....
    }
```

Can anyone pls help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I got it, but I know the html url parsing is not the best way (if you have suggestion on how to parse it better, pls do so). right now, the only goal is to change the href link so here it goes.

```
 public string ScreenScrape()
        {
            string url = "http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/index.php";
            string strResult = "";

            WebResponse objResponse;
            WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                // Close and clean up the StreamReader
                sr.Close();
            }
            var webGet = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            var doc = webGet.Load(url);

            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {

                string removeString ="javascript:jsFormAuth('";
                string removeEnd = "');";
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                String strUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(att.XPath, "(");
                string sub1 = att.Value.Replace(removeString,"");
                string sub2 = sub1.Replace(removeEnd,"");
                att.Value = "http://somewebsite.com/tab/form/" + sub2;

            }

            return doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

        }
```